# Ducted vent hood installation - taping up open penetrations

Tags: ducts, hole, range-hood

I was thinking of installing a ducted range hood in my home but there seems to be a lot of things to watch out for.
I was watching this Youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aPCPX4G7VU&ab_channel=DIYDudes) and one comment about "covering up open penetrations" got me thinking... It does seem like making a hole through an exterior wall and putting a not-so-airtight duct through it would require something like [this](https://www.wconline.com/articles/91635-adhesive-tape-for-exterior-penetrations), but I haven't seen anyone do it, so... is this necessary? And why/why not?

(From additional research it seems what I'm asking about is called "flashing"?)

Answer (score 1):

Flashing does two things:

1. Seal air leaks, which are a major source of inefficiency. If they are big enough they can also lead to pest infiltration. To address this you use sealing materials like foam, caulk, putty, etc.
2. Keep water out of the wall. Though a wood building will survive a little bit of water getting in just fine, it's not great for the long-term health of the structure. This is where modern tape flashing is really coming in to use. If there's a way for water to get on the pipe, you want to make sure it continues down the exterior of the wall rather than going in to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

From the outside and from inside you can fill it around the pipe up with expanding foam to stop the bugs coming in.

Then use the pipe ring/covers (flange) to make it look nice.